# How to copy all the appsetting to Azure App service(windows) when deploying from visual studio

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-appservice, azure-app-service-envrmnt

I have complex hierarchal setting in my appsetting.
when I deploy(using Publish) my App from Visual studio, I am wondering if it does copy the appsetting to Azure, because i am getting error related to one of the setting not being available on azure but present in appsetting.

Do i have to manually create all setting again in Azure App Service.
Also since Azure App service is Key value pair, how do I accommodate hierarchal settings ?

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DatabaseConsString": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"

  },
  "ApplicationInsights": {
    /*XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX*/
    "InstrumentationKey": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
  },
  "RedisCache": {
    "ConnectionString": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
  },
  "sendGrid": {
    "ApiKey": "SG.XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    "FromEmail": "XXXXXXXX@XXXXXXXXXX.net",
    "FromEmailName": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
  },
  "Twilio": {
    "AccountSID": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    "AuthToken": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    "FromNumber": "+XXXXXXXX"
  },
  "Jwt": {
    "key": "MyApplicationKey",
    "Issuer": "MyAppName",
    "Audience": "MyAppAudience"
  },
  "Serilog": {
    "Properties": {
      "ApplicationName": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
      "Serilog": "AppInsightFromSerilog"   
    },
    "MinimumLevel": { //https://docs.datalust.co/v2/docs/logging-levels  (Verbose,Debug,Information,Warning,Error,Fatal)
      "Default": "Information",
      "Override": {
        "Microsoft": "Warning",
        "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
      }
    },
    "Using": [ "XXXXXXXXXXXX.Server", "Serilog.Sinks.ApplicationInsights", "Serilog.Sinks.Console" ],
    "Enrich": [
      "FromLogContext",
      "WithUserName",
      "WithIPAddress"
    ],

    "Filter": [
      {
        "Name": "ByExcluding",
        "Args": {
          "expression": "RequestPath like '%swagger%'  or RequestPath like '%_framework%' or Contains(@m, 'Hosting environment:')  or Contains(@m, 'Now listening on:') or Contains(@m, 'HTTP') or Contains(@m, 'Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.') or Contains(@m, 'Content root path:')"
          //https://github.com/serilog/serilog-expressions
        }
      }
    ],
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "Console"
        //"Args": {
        //  "levelSwitch": "$consoleSwitch"
        //}
      },
      //{
      //  "Name": "File",
      //  "Args": {
      //    "path": "./logs/log-.txt",
      //    "rollingInterval": "Day"
      //  }
      //},
      {
        "Name": "ApplicationInsights",
        "Args": {
          "restrictedToMinimumLevel": "Information",
          "telemetryConverter": "Serilog.Sinks.ApplicationInsights.Sinks.ApplicationInsights.TelemetryConverters.TraceTelemetryConverter, Serilog.Sinks.ApplicationInsights"
        }
      },
      {
        "Name": "MSSqlServer",
        "Args": {
         
          "connectionString": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
          "sinkOptionsSection": {
            "tableName": "SeriLog",
            "formatter": "Serilog.Formatting.Compact.CompactJsonFormatter, Serilog.Formatting.Compact",
            "schemaName": "dbo",
            "autoCreateSqlTable": true
          },
          "columnOptionsSection": {
            //https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-mssqlserver#custom-property-columns
            "additionalColumns": [
              {
                "ColumnName": "InstanceId",
                "PropertyName": "InstanceId",
                "DataType": "varchar",
                "DataLength": 80
              },
              {
                "ColumnName": "ConnectionId",
                "PropertyName": "ConnectionId",
                "DataType": "varchar",
                "DataLength": 80
              },
              {
                "ColumnName": "RequestId",
                "PropertyName": "RequestId",
                "DataType": "varchar",
                "DataLength": 80
              },
              {
                "ColumnName": "ActionId",
                "PropertyName": "ActionId",
                "DataType": "varchar",
                "DataLength": 80
              },
              {
                "ColumnName": "OperationId",
                "PropertyName": "OperationId",
                "DataType": "varchar",
                "DataLength": 80
              },
              {
                "ColumnName": "ActionName",
                "PropertyName": "ActionName",
                "DataType": "varchar",
                "DataLength": 5000
              },
              {
                "ColumnName": "EnvironmentName",
                "PropertyName": "EnvironmentName",
                "DataType": "varchar",
                "DataLength": 50
              },
              {
                "ColumnName": "ApplicationName",
                "PropertyName": "ApplicationName",
                "DataType": "varchar",
                "DataLength": 5000
              },
              {
                "ColumnName": "UserName",
                "PropertyName": "UserName",
                "DataType": "varchar",
                "DataLength": 1000
              },
              {
                "ColumnName": "IPAddress",
                "PropertyName": "IPAddress",
                "DataType": "varchar",
                "DataLength": 50
              },
              {
                "ColumnName": "Source",
                "PropertyName": "Source",
                "DataType": "varchar",
                "DataLength": 50
              },
              {
                "ColumnName": "SourceContext",
                "PropertyName": "SourceContext",
                "DataType": "varchar",
                "DataLength": 1000
              },
              {
                "ColumnName": "Origin",
                "PropertyName": "Origin",
                "DataType": "varchar",
                "DataLength": 100
              },
              {
                "ColumnName": "OperationType",
                "PropertyName": "OperationType",
                "DataType": "varchar",
                "DataLength": 1000
              },
              {
                "ColumnName": "RequestPath",
                "PropertyName": "RequestPath",
                "DataType": "varchar",
                "DataLength": 1000
              },
              {
                "ColumnName": "MethodName",
                "PropertyName": "MethodName",
                "DataType": "varchar",
                "DataLength": 1000
              }
            ],
            "addStandardColumns": [ "LogEvent" ],
            "removeStandardColumns": [ "MessageTemplate", "Properties" ],
            "logEvent": {
              "excludeAdditionalProperties": true,
              "excludeStandardColumns": true
            }
          },
          "restrictedToMinimumLevel": "Information" // (Verbose,Debug,Information,Warning,Error,Fatal)
        }

      }
    ]
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"

}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to directly add your `appsettings.json` file values in app service `application settings/connection settings`.

Instead you can use the below ways to achieve this by after deploying it into azure. Refer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-common#edit-in-bulk)

When you deploy your webapp to Azure App Services, usually `appsettings.json` is not deployed.  So you have to use Azure Portal **Application Settings** blade to upload your settings. In Azure App Services, you can use either use Application Settings or Connection Strings. If you save in the Connection String, you have to use **GetConnectionString()** API.

In azure **Application Settings** blade click the **Advanced edit** button. When finished, click **Update**. Don't forget to click **Save** back in the **Configuration** page.

Make sure your json file format should be in below format

```
[
    {
        "name": "<key-1>",
        "value": "<value-1>",
        "slotSetting": false
    },
    {
        "name": "<key-2>",
        "value": "<value-2>",
        "slotSetting": false
    },
    ...
]
```

By using CLI we can add the multiple application settings to your web app service

For adding Single appsetting value

```
az webapp config appsettings set --name <app-name> --resource-group <resource-group-name> --settings <setting-name>="<value>"
```

For adding the appsettings value using .json file

```
az  webapp  config  appsettings  set  --resource-group <resource-group-name>  --name <app-name>  --settings  mySetting=value  "@moresettings.json"
```

Refer [here](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/apps-on-azure/asp-net-core-appsettings-for-azure-app-service/ba-p/392596)